# Entity Reference and nested arguments in Views

Tags: nodes, entities, views

My site has 3 nodes:

- **Program**, which is a list of **Course** nodes.
- **Course**, which contains basic information about a course you can take
- **Course Date**, a specific instance of a **Course**. Each **Course Date** references one **Course**, and the titles are auto-generated.

The view I'm scratching my head over is

- I need a view that loads on each **Program** node, showing all current **Course Dates** who's Entity Reference matches any **Course** in the current **Program**.

It would be a lot simpler if each **Course** was only in one **Program**, but they aren't.

I've tried Relation and found it too buggy for production. I've tried Reference and Entity Reference, and settled on the latter as it seems more featured.

Would it be possible to automate some kind of reverse field reference? Any tips welcome!

Comment: Do you need this "I need a view that loads on each Program node, showing all current Course Dates who's Entity Reference matches any Course in the current Program." or this "Would it be possible to automate some kind of reverse field reference?" or both?

Comment: If anyone's interested, I used Boriana's answer along with Draggable Views to make something less extensible but functional!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Entity Reference does implement reverse pointers, so to speak.

On your program view, which I suppose has entity reference fields to course nodes, first set up a **Relationship** (under the 'Advanced' view section) that will link to the view the specific Course nodes that exist for the current program as entity references.

- If you go to add a relationship, you'll get a dialog that looks like this:

[image]

- Set it to filter the potential relationships to ones using 'Entity Reference' fields.
- Select the '**Referenced entity**' field that exists in the Program content type to point to its Courses (whatever you called it).  You can choose to change its name to 'Referenced course' or something short like that for later.  You can also limit the view to include only Programs that *have* course fields by checking that 'Require relationship' box!
- Now all those course nodes are available in your view (you can add their fields to your view if you need to)
- Next, add one more relationship.  This time look for the relationship that is a '**Referencing entity**' (as opposed to 'Referenced entity') for your Course Date node.  That will provide a link to all Course Date nodes, which themselves reference the current Course node.  When setting up this second relationship, make sure you select the previous relationship to be used in the 'Relationship' dropdown.  After all, this reverse reference points to the course node of the current program, not to the current program itself, right?
- Finally, you should now be able to add fields for course nodes and course date nodes that relate to your program, because of these two relationships.  Just make sure the fields you add, have the correct Relationship set from the relationship drop-down.  That way they will pull from the correct node.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, my brain is still fairly confused though! Should the main View be filtering for Programs, Courses or Course Dates? Also the view is on the program node, not the course node. Thanks for the help though, just trying to get my head around the referencing node bridges!

Comment: Ah, yes, I see.  Since this is actually a view of programs that is displaying the 'Program' content types fields, you'd need one extra relationship in there.  You'd first need to get the 'Course' relationship set up (as 'Referenced entity') and *then* add a second relationship that links the Course Date 'Referencing entity' using the already added relationship.  I'll edit my response in a few to see if that makes more sense!

Comment: Hmm. For now I'm trying to make a Rule to make a reverse node reference for the sake of my poor brain :) will let you know how I get on tomorrow!

This solved an unrelated issue I had though :)

Comment: Which point or step are you having trouble with?  I can definitely get a working example working, so I may be able to help.  Let me know if there's a specific step in the process that you can't get, and I can provide an extra screenshot or so if needed.  :-)

Comment: The crux of it is getting the Program into the Course Dates view! I can get the Course to load in as a Referenced Entity, but I can't work out how to get a relationship in from a node that is 2 links away :)

Comment: Ah, I see.  If you read the beginning part though, I'm just setting it up as a view of program nodes.... Does may help! ;-) I modified my answer yesterday to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

May be you could try (and adapt) this snippet in the contextual filter based on your entity reference field of your view

```
$ Node = menu_get_object ()   // we get the current node
switch ($ node-> type) {          // We can manage multiple scenarios depending on the type of content
  case 'type A':                          // For the content type A
    $ Related_ids = array ();
    $ Related = field_get_items ('node', $node, 'YOUR_FIELD_ENTITY_REFERENCE')    // Get the entity reference scope
    if ($related && is_array ($related) && sizeof ($related)> 0) {
      for ($i = 0; $i <count ($related); $i++) {
        $ Related_ids [] = $related[$ i]['target_id'];
      }
    }
    return implode ('+', $related_ids) // It returns the values ​​of the field entity reference

  default:
    return 0 / / default it returns 0
}
```

See this [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1714188) for further informations